# Getting the most from a single MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website that lists apartments that are available for rent.  I have a few different tables in my MySQL database.  One table is for basic information about the Apartment building as a whole, including address, ammenities, photos, an ID (NID), etc.

Another table lists the units available for rent within each building.  So each apartment building has multiple floorplans, with a few studios, a few 1 bedroom units, sometimes a few 2 bedroom units, etc.

Currently I query my 'unit' table and ask for all units in a given apartment building.  My query looks something like `SELECT * FROM node_unit WHERE nid='555'`

This might return something like the following:

```
NID    Name       Rent    SqFT    Bedrooms    Bathrooms
555    Unit 1     $500    620      0            1
555    Unit 2     $550    680      0            1
555    Unit 3     $600    820      1            1
555    Unit 4     $650    920      1            1
555    Unit 5     $700    1220     2            1
555    Unit 6     $800    1420     2            2
555    Unit 7     $900    1500     3            2
555    Unit 8     $1100   1620     3            3
```

etc, etc

What I am then doing in my PHP is using an accordian to group the 1 bedrooms together, the 2 bedrooms together, etc.

Not all apartments have 2 bedrooms units, some only have 1 bedroom units, so I need to know within my PHP code if I should print another accordian.

Currently I am using multiple hits to the database to determine if a given building has any 2 bedroom units, if so print another row.  Does this building have any 3 bedroom units?  If so print another row, but I would like to stop hitting my database so much.

Finally, here is my question:

How can I store the results from my first DB call and somehow parse thru the data and and determine if a given NID has studios, 1 beds, 2 beds, etc?  (I just started learning PHP/MySQL recently)

Comment: Please post your current script, otherwise it is much harder to make a suggestion.

Comment: As long as the result volume does not exceed certain size limits you can retrieve all entries in the result and simply store them in a php array. Then you have all time of the world to go through that and extract whatever information you need. Not sure if that is faster, though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM node_unit WHERE nid='555'
ORDER BY Bedrooms ASC, Bathrooms ASC, Rent ASC
```

This would return your records ordered by # of bedrooms, # bathrooms, and rent amount (in that order).

You could easily store this in multidimensional array when reading from database like this (assuming `mysqli` use with result set stored in `$result`, but concept is same for other DB connection libraries)

```
$room_array = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $room_array[(int)$row['Bedrooms']][] = $row;
}
```

You now have a multidimensional array with number of bedrooms as first index. The array might look like this if you `var_dump` it:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            'NID' => '555',
            'Name' => 'Unit 1',
            'Rent' => '$500',
            'SqFt' => '620',
            'Bedrooms' => '0',
            'Bathrooms' => '1',
        )
        [1] => Array (
            'NID' => '555',
            'Name' => 'Unit 2',
            'Rent' => '$550',
            'SqFt' => '680',
            'Bedrooms' => '0',
            'Bathrooms' => '1',
        )
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            'NID' => '555',
            'Name' => 'Unit 3',
            'Rent' => '$600',
            'SqFt' => '820',
            'Bedrooms' => '1',
            'Bathrooms' => '1',
        )
        [1] => Array (
            'NID' => '555',
            'Name' => 'Unit 4',
            'Rent' => '$650',
            'SqFt' => '920',
            'Bedrooms' => '1',
            'Bathrooms' => '1',
        )
    [2] => Array (
        ...
    )
    [3] => Array (
        ...
    )
)
```

This makes it really easy to iterate over the number of bedrooms values in an outer loop, which creates your accordions, and then iterate the individual rooms in an inner loop.

```
foreach ($room_array as $num_bedrooms => $rooms) {
    // start accordion
    foreach ($rooms as $room) {
        // output room details
    }
    // end accordion
}
```

All this would only require the single query.

Also make sure you have indexes on bedrooms, bathrooms, rent (or whichever you use in the sort) as well as on nid since it is used as the filter.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  This seems like a good way to go about it.  Using your code I was able to setup an array and then using print_r within the foreach I can see that the array is setting the data correctly.  On my end Bedrooms is the 5th index and not the first, I am not sure that matters.

I was wondering though, now that the data is in an array, how can I grab only the 1 bedrooms, or 2 bedrooms?  The foreach example you listed loops thru but I want to group items into the accordion.  I'm sure I'm just missing something simple.  Can I just say something like "If index [5] = "3" then ...

Comment: I figured it out, just needed another loop:

 `if ($room['5'] == 0) 
  echo "studios";
 if ($room['5'] == 1) 
  echo "1 bedrooms";`

Comment: You must not have set up the array the way I mentioned.  I have added a sample of what a var_dump would look like if done the way I mentioned.  The first level of the array represents a grouping of teh number of bedrooms.  Everything with 0 index for first dimension would have 0 bedrooms, everything with 1 index would have one bedroom, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this as your database query, it will generate a row for each building for each unit type it has.  You could also use it as a subquery and join to the parent table to get any other details you need about the building in one shot.

```
select 'studio' as unit_type, nid from node_unit group by nid having count(case when bedrooms = 0 then 1 end) > 0
union all
select 'one bedroom' as unit_type, nid from node_unit group by nid having count(case when bedrooms = 1 then 1 end) > 0
union all
select 'two bedroom' as unit_type, nid from node_unit group by nid having count(case when bedrooms = 2 then 1 end) > 0
union all
select 'three bedroom' as unit_type, nid from node_unit group by nid having count(case when bedrooms = 3 then 1 end) > 0
```

Comment: This would be a very inefficient query.  If you want to have a string value returned as a unit type you would be much better served taking the query shown in my answer and just putting a case statement in the SELECT like `SELECT nid, name, rent, sqft, (CASE WHEN bedrooms = 0 THEN 'studio' WHEN bedrooms = 1 THEN 'one_bedroom' WHEN bedrooms = 2 THEN 'two bedrooms' WHEN bedrooms = 3 THEN 'three bedrooms' END CASE) as unit_type, bedrooms, bathrooms FROM node_unit WHERE nid='555' ORDER BY bedrooms ASC, bathrooms ASC, rent ASC`

Comment: Sure, your suggestion is more efficient, but it doesn't generate a new row for each building and room combination for easy binding to the UI Jay is after.  There are ways of generating the same result set without having four passes on the table, but based on the audience, I didn't think getting too advanced would be appropriate.